# SOAP webservice call using Retrofit is possible?

Tags: java, android, soap, retrofit, retrofit2

Retrofit is A type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java, My question is that To call SOAP API which is in .NET server. Is it possible to use Retrofit interface api methods for webservice call methods POST, GET, PUT, DELETE.  If yes share me the each and every methods example. Advance thanks

Comment: did you get the answer?

Comment: No bro none responded with answer to this topic

Comment: Did any one get answer of this question ?

Comment: NO, But some article suggested to do wrapper class of own but there was no sufficient example snippet to understand the matter so I give up this. Hence I am using the usual soap call with KSOAP library.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, am working on such a project where i have decided to use Retrofit for SOAP implementation. For now I am referring to [SOAP with Retrofit](https://snow.dog/blog/android-and-magento-soap-api-part-i/), also using [For XML serialization & De-serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#start), so that I can use POJOs.